# Edit castorbuilder.properties file

Tags: java, xml, castor

Does anyone know how to provide their own castorbuilder.properties file or extend the existing castorbuilder.properties file?

I'm trying to generate source code for an XSD using SourceGeneratorMain. I want to modify the conflict name resolver.

I know the existing build file is located at: org/exolab/castor/builder/castorbuilder.properties. But I can't edit because it's in the jar.

Is there an easy way to feed in your own properties through SourceGeneratorMain?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new castorbuilder.properties file containing just the properties you want to override and place it in your classpath.

More info: http://castor.codehaus.org/1.3/srcgen-properties.html